# why does my emberjs model throw an exception when i try calling deleteRecord on it

Tags: ember.js

I am doing this tutorial and just when i thought i got everything right, I came across this exception

```
 JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'deleteRecord'
```

in this context

```
removeTodo: function () {
        var todo = this.get('model');
        todo.deleteRecord();
        todo.save();
    }
```

i trying to follow the getting started tutorial on the [Ember.js site](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/deleting-todos/).

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your model isn't actually a DS.Model (assuming that you're using Ember Data). Unless you're model is an actual record I'm ember, you won't be able to call delete record.

Comment: I can't pinpoint what i missed from the tutorial, but when i copy their version of the code exactly it doesn't throw the error.  There must be a small step I missed.  I will try again later. Thanks